# Get content types field in another content type with the entity reference relationship

Tags: views, entities

I have two content types. Person and Projects. I use a entity reference for the persons name on the project node so people can select the person that is involved in the project. Now using that reference I also want to get another field from the persons content type, and display this. I can't figure out how to do this. I thought I could do it with a views. I created a view with a relationship and filter with NID but it just doesn't seem to work. Whats the simplest way (view or not) to do this?

Comment: Do you want to display the field in the edit view?

Comment: Hi Huelfe, sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I want to display it on the projects node

Comment: If you want to display it in a node, create a view mode for person. After that go to display settings of projects and change the view mode of your referenced field.

Answer (score 0):

With [Entity Reference Autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill) You can achieve something like you specified.

> > The Entity reference autofill module gives Entity reference fields an option to populate other form fields with data from selected referenced entities.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply this looks like it might be what I want but I'm struggling to understand how to set this up. So I already had a entity reference to the person content type in projects. And the e-mail field in persons. So I create another entity reference in projects with autofill? I'm unclear how I piggy back off the reference.